# Relationship between file created with dentry inode and open syscall inode?

Tags: linux, file, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am creating a simple `debugfs` file inside `/sys/kernel/debug/test/testFile` using the following code:

```
pDebugfs = debugfs_create_dir(name, NULL);

if (!pDebugfs)
            goto fail;          

if (!debugfs_create_file("testFile", MODE_T, pDebugfs,
        NULL,  &debugfs_fops)) {
    goto fail;
}
```

And now when I write to this file, `open` method will be called which has the definition:

```
static ssize_t debugfs_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
```

Now the `pDebugfs` which is of type `dentry` has a pointer to an `inode` called `d_inode` as defined [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/dcache.h#L108).

My question is what is the relationship between this `inode` pointer and the one called in `open`? Are they related? If yes, how? I tried to print the `i_flags` value in both the `i_node` definitions but they don't match, I assign `i_flags` in `init` and just check its value in `open` but they don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have two `dentry`. One that create the directory in `/sys/kernel/debug/`

```
pDebugfs = debugfs_create_dir(name, NULL);
```

and, you are not storing it but it is there, one that create the file you `open(2)`:

```
pDebugfs_file = debugfs_create_file("testFile", MODE_T, pDebugfs, NULL,  &debugfs_fops)
```

The `inode` you see in `debugfs_open` is the one associated to the file
and not to the directory.